# Wordpress - link is being stripped when I post, how to stop?

Tags: wordpress

When I try to post this:

```
<a class="post-handle" href="#" data-timestamp="2.09">my link</a>
```

The post ends up as:

```
<a class="post-handle" href="#">my link</a>
```

How can I stop WP from swallowing the `data-timestamp="2.16"` portion?

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25479795/3236352) or [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/97757/69071)

Comment: Would you wanna use jQuery to solve this? Or it has to be done by server-side?

Comment: If you have a solution either way, please tell me.

Comment: ended up using the solution here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97303/wordpress-removing-data-attributes-for-scheduled-post/97757#97757